# How tall are each of the colossi?

Tags: shadow-of-the-colossus

I want to make a model of some of the colossi, can anyone tell me how large each of the colossi is?  Height, width, depth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order of appearance:

**Valus** is roughly 70 feet (21M) tall.
**Quadratus** is about 98 feet high, and 115 ft long from head to tail.
**Gaius** is 97 feet tall.
**Phaedra** is 98 feet tall, and about 90 feet long.
**Avion** is 140 feet from beak to tail with a 130 foot wingspan.
**Barba** is 80 feet tall.
**Hydrus** is 280 feet long.
**Kuromori** is 16 feet tall, and only 56 feet long.
**Basaran** is 75 feet tall, 160 feet in length.
**Dirge** is 260 feet long.
**Celosia** is tied as the smallest colossus at only 12 feet tall and 18 feet long.
**Pelagia** is 89 feet tall, and 100 feet long.
**Phalanx** is absolutely massive (the largest colossus in fact), clocking in at 557 feet long, with a wingspan of 200 feet.
**Cenobia** is the other smallest colossus at 12 high and 18 long.
**Argus** is 75 feet tall.
**Malus** is 195 feet tall -  roughly double the height of any of the other 'upright' colossi.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't have a direct answer to your question, I was able to find this [comparison picture](http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/The_colossi).

I imagine that if you could somehow come by the game's art book, from which that picture is taken, you'd have it at a higher quality.

Since I suspect your models won't be to scale, then a relative comparison might be sufficient in the stead of absolute measurements.

Answer (score 3):

After following the link provided by Aubergine I found the de-facto number from the ICO team itself.  70 feet/21 meters tall.  In the trivia section of http://teamico.wikia.com/wiki/Valus

Comment: I will leave the originally accepted answer as that for now. I am not sure how I feel about accepting my own answer, what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

To add to Aubergine's answer, it appears that the whole artbook is on Picasa. So, here's [a bigger rendition](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_J1Y2Gif69BA/TJcz-NwVauI/AAAAAAAANNw/GFy2wN5o88Q/142.jpg) of the same comparison picture.

Comment: Thank you, the combination of both of these answers have helped me find many more pictures that will assist me greatly!